# depth wrong using openni_camera depth image

Tags: kinect, openni, openni-camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I install ubuntu10.10 independently on my macbook pro. And ROS unstable with Openni_kinect. (I know the unstable is a little old, but I am sure it is not the reason.)

I could only get a very low frame rate when use a kinect camera, with the command of rosbag record -a,
I find that the frame rate is just about 3fps. Even when I just record a single topic, the fps is still low, is about 8 fps, with a extremely big file.

I still have another problem that when I get the depth image with my kinect, I could only get a few depth value like 0,1,2,3,4,5.

Can you help me about this?

Regards
Wei

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9260/depth-wrong-using-openni_camera-depth-image/) by [Bruce](https://answers.ros.org/users/224/bruce/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2011-03-02

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-03-02**:
Also please try to ask one question at a time.  Otherwise they are harder to index and find later.  You can edit this question to update the above and remove the 2nd question.  And then ask the 2nd question independently.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-03-02**:
Are you logging on the same computer? http://answers.ros.org/question/220/kinect-data-via-router-to-host-pc  It looks like your hardware might be having trouble keeping up, especially if logging fewer topics improves performance.  Could you provide more details on exactly what you're running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The depth image isn't (usually) what you want; you usually want the point cloud, which has units of meters.

The slow recording is trickier to diagnose; are there known issues with USB speeds on macbooks in Linux?

---

Originally posted by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) with karma: 4119 on 2011-06-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1